# JSON viewer that can query data using a key in a JSON object

Tags: json

I was wondering if there is an online tool that could get specific data from array of json objects

For example, I have this JSON array

```
{ "results": [
    {
        "createdAt": "2015-09-02T02:03:55.765Z",
        "name": "Clush",
        "score": 15,
        "updatedAt": "2015-09-12T21:03:57.773Z",
        "userId": "5645645"
    },
    {
        "createdAt": "2015-09-06T00:17:52.225Z",
        "name": "hello",
        "score": 9,
        "updatedAt": "2015-09-06T07:41:27.749Z",
        "userId": ""
    },
    {
        "createdAt": "2015-09-08T01:21:09.970Z",
        "name": "test",
        "score": 50,
        "updatedAt": "2015-09-08T01:21:14.787Z"
    },
    {
        "createdAt": "2015-09-08T01:21:20.037Z",
        "name": "test2",
        "score": 88,
        "updatedAt": "2015-09-08T01:21:23.140Z"
    },
    {
        "createdAt": "2015-08-27T02:13:35.869Z",
        "name": "Hana",
        "score": 8,
        "updatedAt": "2015-09-11T20:39:36.037Z",
        "userId": "7678889"
    }
] }
```

I want only to get the values under name field
and save it on separate file.

So on my other file i should only have

```
Clush
hello
test
test2
Hana
```

I have look at some JSON viewer but it seems they dont have this 
functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another service is https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/

It uses JsonPath (*https://www.google.com/search?q=jsonpath&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8*)

So querying for `$..name` will get an array with only the name values (*you need to select the **stefan goessner** implementation from the dropdown on the right*).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this service: http://ashphy.com/JSONPathOnlineEvaluator/

In the Inputs textbox enter **$.results[*].name**

and in the Evaluation Results pane you would get

```
'0' => "Clush"
'1' => "hello"
'2' => "test"
'3' => "test2"
'4' => "Hana"
```